# upload videos on amazon s3 bucket and get a streamable video path

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I need to convert base64 data to '.mp4' file and then upload it to the Amazon S3 bucket. When I am trying to access the path, err "file cannot be played because it is corrupted" is shown. I have checked through DragonDisk that my file is uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Below is my code:

```js
var accessKeyId = config.s3.S3_KEY;
var secretAccessKey = config.s3.S3_SECRET;
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    apiVersion: {
        s3: "2006-03-01"
    }
});
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var video = "user_" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + ".mp4";
path = '';

var bitmap = new Buffer(data.message, 'base64');
fs.writeFile(video, bitmap, function (err) {

if (err) {
    console.log("write file error")
    console.log(err);
    callback(err, {});
} else {
    var bodyStream = fs.createReadStream(video);
    var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: "users_videos/" + video, Body: bodyStream, ACL: 'public-read',ContentType: "video/mp4"};
    s3.putObject(params, function (err, dataa) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("inside putobject error");
            console.log(err);
            path = '';
            callback(err, {});
        }
        else {
            path = "http://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/users_videos/" + video;
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data to Bucket");
            console.log(path);

            fs.unlink(video, function (err) {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("deleted file");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think here is your answer: [Stack Overflow: How to get the progress status of the file uploaded to Amazon S3 using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47989714/11758843)